# Time Complexity in Reversing a C++ String

Tags: c++, string, big-o, space-complexity

I have a problem on my homework to reverse the words in a C++ string, in place, with only O(1) additional memory. I'm confused by what it means O(1) additional memory. I understand what O(1) generally means, where no matter how big the input is, the time to compute will be constant so I'm guessing I should add only one piece of memory that would keep track of the words in reverse. Any suggestions?

Comment: It means a constant amount of extra memory--the amount of extra memory needed is unaffected by the length of string, length of a word, number of words, etc.

Comment: so does this mean i need a constant piece of memory that should output each word in reverse and move on to the next word? I'm gameplanning how i can do this

Comment: What do you mean by reversing the words? "hello world" to "world hello", or to "dlrow olleh"?

Comment: It means you need a constant-*sized* piece of memory. How you use it is up to you.

Comment: Not necessarily. O(1) means m < k for space needed m and some constant k. m could be a function, not necessarily a constant itself, it just needs to be bounded above by a constant.

Comment: yes, hello world would become world hello, and C++11 is great! would become great!is C++11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O(1) additional memory means "using at most some constant additional memory."  For example, you couldn't store a copy of the string, since that would take O(n) space, but you could store any constant number of extra `int`s, `char`s, etc.

More generally- statements like "O(1)" or "O(n)" don't necessarily refer to runtimes.  Big-O notation is a way of describing functions.  An algorithm can't be O(n), but its *runtime* can be O(n).  An algorithm's space usage can similarly be O(1), O(n), O(2<sup>n</sup>), etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not entirely correct. A copy of my comment on the queston: O(1) means m < k for space needed m and some constant k. m could be a function, not necessarily a constant itself, it just needs to be bounded above by a constant.

Comment: so I would be allowed to store any amound of ints, or chars but as long as I don't create a piece of memory that depends on the length, making it O(N), then this satisfies the memory constraint

Comment: for swap, would this be appropiate. swap(string.at(0),str.at(str.length()). Would this swap the first and last character of the string

Comment: @JoshHamet- Yep!  Each of those calls uses only a constant amount of space, and the swap call only uses a constant amount of overhead.

Comment: okay last question, my idea that im executing so far is to locating each space and cout the substrings between the spaces. I don't believe this would be O(N) but part of me believes it is

Comment: @JoshHamet- Be careful - if you're finding and storing substrings somewhere, your memory usage will be O(n) if one of the substrings is a long substring.  Here's a hint: try reversing the entire string first.  What happens then?

Comment: @templatetypedef: It depends whether your "substring" is a copy or a shim. A shim is O(1) size, just pointers to the begin and the end of the substring within the actual string.